# Drupal 7: add 2 styles for block

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I want to allow webmaster while adding a new block to choose the style ( with padding, without padding ) , there is a module named block_class which allow me to add a css class for each block , it work but I want something better like using a select box  .. , someone told me to use stylizer module but I don't know how to relate it with blocks ..